# Find and deserialization object in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I tried to deserialize an object with MongoDB Driver, and getting an error. my code is very similar to the example code in mongodb formal site, and I can't find where is my mistake.

This is the error:

```
"Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class mongotry.place."
```

And the code:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;

class place{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<int> rates { get; set; }

    public place(string name, List<int> rates){...}
    public int getAvgRate(){...}             
    public override string ToString(){...}
}

class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){           
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        MongoServer server = client.GetServer();       
        MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("try");
        MongoCollection<place> myPlaces = db.GetCollection<place>("places");

        myPlaces.Insert(new place("here", new List<int> {7,7,5,4,9}););
        myPlaces.Insert(new place("there", new List<int> { 2, 4, 1, 4});); //ok so far

        place placeFromDB = myPlaces.FindOne(); // <-- here is the error.
        Console.WriteLine(placeFromDB.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add id property to your place class:

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

You can also mark your name property with `[BsonId]` attribute, however having ObjectId property is more powerful - it contains timestamp/increment id/machine info within itself ans is always unique.

Comment: What if you don't want to add an Id or _id property to your class? I don't care about that field... if mongodb wants to add it to each record in the database that's fine, but when it serializes back into my class it would be nice if it just serialized all the other properties and ignored the id field. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I guess I should have waited a few more minutes. I found the answer to my own question. If you use the '[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]' then you don't have to put an _id property on your class and it will still create one in the database and still de-serialize to your class without an error.

Comment: That is not always the case, if you are using dynamic objects and the class does not exist. you dont have a property to annotate.
Insert(new { Text = "hello world"}); the class doesnt exists.